# Refining an expression

Tags: trigonometry

So in my textbook I am asked to find the **sin**,**cos** and **tan** functions of the angle $\frac{9\pi}{4} - \frac{5\pi}{6}$

I managed to get the **sin** and **cos**, but I am having a problem finding the **tan**

**Formula** : $\tan(u - v) = \frac{\tan(u) - \tan(v)}{1+\tan(u)\tan(v)}$

Following the formula I got this : $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1 - \sqrt{3}}$

In the answers is this : $2+\sqrt3$

I checked the answer in Symolab and I see that my answer is correct and after some refining I can get to the one in the textbook. The problem is that I can't figure out what I can do to get to it. Can you please help ?

Comment: If you manged to get the $\sin$ and $\cos$, simply divide the former by the latter to get the $\tan$. o.O

Comment: You say that the angle is "$\tan\left(\frac{9\pi}{4}-\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)$."  But do you actually mean that the angle is $\frac{9\pi}{4}-\frac{5\pi}{6}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1 - \sqrt{3}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1 - \sqrt{3}}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1 + \sqrt{3}} = \frac{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}{-2}=\frac{4+2\sqrt{3}}{-2}=-(2+\sqrt{3})$$

There is a small mistake you might have done $\tan(5\pi/6)=-\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}$. So, you will get $$\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{ \sqrt{3}-1} = +(2+\sqrt{3})$$

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(y)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(y)}$$ with $x=\frac{9\pi}{4}$ an d $y=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ we get $$\tan(\pi/12)=2+\sqrt{3}$$